# How to set minimum string length for preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to validate user input in a php script.  I want the var to be only lower case letters with a minimum length of four characters.  I tried the following:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]{4}+$/', $my_var)
```

But this only matches if the string is exactly 4 characters in length.  How can you say at least 4 with no maximum?

Comment: 5 seconds on goggle `{4,}`

Comment: `{4,}` - a range with no upper bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]{4,}+$/', $my_var)
```

`{4,}` will match strings of length 4 or more.